# How do I make my code convert Roman Numerals to numbers?

Tags: java, roman-numerals

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = promptUserForNumber(userInput);
    String romanNum = convertNumberToNumeral(number);
    System.out.println("The number " + number + " is the Roman " + "numeral " + romanNum);

}

private static int promptUserForNumber(Scanner inScanner) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 3999 "
            + "(0 to quit): ");
    int number = inScanner.nextInt();
    if (number == 0){
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
         System.exit(0);
            }                                            
    while (number < 0 || number > 3999){
        System.out.print("Error! Please enter a number "  + "between 1 and 3999 (0 to quit): ");
            number = inScanner.nextInt();
            if (number == 0){                   
            }

    }
    return number;
 }

private static String convertNumberToNumeral(int number) {
    int ones = 0, tens = 0, hunds = 0, thous = 0; 
    String romanOne = "",romanTen = "", romanHunds = "", romanThous = "";
     while(number >= 1000) {
            number -= 1000;
            thous++;
        }

        while(number >= 100) {
            number -= 100;
            hunds++;
        }

        while(number >= 10) {
            number -= 10;
            tens++;
        }

        while(number >= 1) {
            number--;
            ones++;
        }



        while(thous > 0) {
            romanThous += "M";
            thous--;
        }

       if (hunds > 0) {
             if (hunds < 4)
                 while (hunds > 0){
                     romanHunds += "C";
                     hunds--;
                 }
            else if (hunds == 4){
                 romanHunds += "CD";
             }
            else if (hunds == 5){
                 romanHunds += "D";
             }
            else if (hunds == 6 ){
                 romanHunds += "DC";   
             }
                 else if (hunds ==7 ){
                 romanHunds += "DCC";   
             }
             else if (hunds == 8 ){
                 romanHunds += "DCCC";   
             }
             else if (hunds == 9){
                 romanHunds += "CM";
             }
        }

       if (tens > 0) {
           if (tens < 4){
               while (tens > 0){
                   romanTen += "X";
                   tens--;
               }
           }
           else if (tens == 4){
               romanTen += "XL";
           }
           else if (tens == 5){
               romanTen +=  "L";
               }
           else if (tens ==6){
               romanTen += "LX";
           }
            else if (tens ==7){
               romanTen += "LXX";
           }
            else if (tens ==8){
               romanTen += "LXXX";
           }
            else if (tens ==9){
               romanTen += "XC";
           }

           }


        if(ones > 0) {
            if(ones < 4) {
                while(ones > 0) {
                    romanOne += "I";
                    ones--;
                }
            }
            else if(ones == 4) {
                romanOne += "IV";
            } 
            else if(ones == 5) {
                romanOne += "V";
            }
            else if(ones == 6) {
                romanOne += "VI";                
            }
            else if (ones == 7){
                romanOne += "VII";
            }
            else if (ones ==8){
                romanOne += "VIII";
            }

            else {
                romanOne = "IX";
            }
        }

        return romanThous + romanHunds + romanTen + romanOne;
}



{

    } 

}
```

// This code does number to roman numeral, but i was thinking there was a way to convert the coding i already have, to roman numeral to number. I don't know how i would do this. I think i would have to change something in my method convertNumberToNumeral. I don't know how to do it though.

Comment: First 2 results on google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073150/converting-roman-numerals-to-decimal and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313254/roman-numeral-to-number-conversion

Comment: Do you know how to change my code given, to do what i want? The links given don't use the same methods and stuff

Comment: Maybe because your method is too complicated? Check the example I gave you. You should be able to do something with that ;)

Comment: I have use those methods for my class

Comment: i have to follow the skeleton